# Cannot handle action events on Labels?

Tags: codenameone

I've dynamically created a horizontal scrolling list of labels (with icon and bottom text) within a container in a tab.

However, I cannot seem to bind any action to this Label - I want touch, long press, options(commands), drag, etc

If I use Button instead of Label, I cannot seem to use URLImage to grab the icon from a url and save it to storage and use that as the button icon. It always uses only the placeholder from:

```
Image img = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, counter+"_thumbnail", thumbnailURL, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE);
```

How do I grab events on the Labels? Here is a snippet of how I'm adding the labels to the container:

```
Container c = StateMachine.instance.findFirstListContainer();
for(...){
    Label l = new Label();
    l.setText(title);  
    l.setIcon(img);
    l.setUIID("listItem");
    l.setTextPosition(2);
    c.addComponent(l);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Button` rather than a `Label` and invoke the `setUIID("Label")` method.

The reason why you didn't do this is a separate question/issue: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/5HoDEFjB5II/5dc4iKuYNSYJ